# The problem when I calculate the derivative

Tags: calculus, matrix-calculus

$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{f}(a)\|_2^2$
and $\mathbf{f}$ is $\mathbb R^1\to\mathbb R^n$.

The problem I encountered is that the chain rule dimension.
Is the following derivation correct?

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{f}(a)\|_2^2=\mathbf{f}(a)\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\mathbf{f}(a)$$
However I do not know how does the $\cdot$ operate.

Comment: It is a dot product.

Comment: @GReyes How do I see that?

Comment: As $||f(a)||^2=\langle f(a),f(a)\rangle$ just use the product rule to get $\langle f(a), f'(a)\rangle$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Thank you.